# Input field wont function (Can't type text in it)

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have a search box which slides out when you click on a div but it wont let me put any text in and I can't find a reason why.

```js
$('#searchh').click(function() {
  $('.search-button').animate({
    'left': '520px'
  });
});

$('#searchh').click(function() {
  $('.search-balk').animate({
    'width': '295px'
  });
});
```

```css
.search-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 225px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.8s, color 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.8s, color 1s;
  transition: background-position 0.8s, color 1s;
}
.search-balk {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  height: 71px;
  width: 260px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 33;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-button">
  <input class="search-balk" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Vul hier je zoekwoord in...">
  <img src="/assets/images/search.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: `#searchh` doesn't exist in your HTML??

Comment: yes it does but not needed here its atm my entire navbar first wanted to fix this then change the spot to activate the input field

Comment: The slide works but i cant type text in my field

Comment: Problem in your example is not that you can't type, problem is that part of the input is hidden so you need to write enough characters to text start showing up. Write more than 9 characters and you'll see what I mean

Comment: @ClaudioRedi That doesnt solve the problem either i cant even select it

Comment: Than you probably didn't post the whole code, because the JSFiddle is working fine.

Comment: Remove or change the `right: 50px`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove 
    .search-button
    {
      /* position: absolute; */
    }

and you see what the problem is try to make a div on top of it and gief it position relative.